# How to have a controlled file upload button in material-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have columns like this :-

```
const columns = [
  {
    field: "truck_in_time",
    title: "Truck in time",
    editable: "never",
  },
  {
    field: "truck_out_time",
    title: "Truck out time",
    editable: "never",
  },
  {
    field: "document",
    title: "Document",
    width: 160,
    render: (params) => {
      return (
        <>
          <button
            onClick={() => console.log(params)}
            className="productListEdit"
          >
            Upload
          </button>
        </>
      );
    },
    editable: "never",
  },
  {
    field: "remarks",
    title: "Remarks",
    width: 160,
    editable: "onUpdate",
  },
];
```

I want something for upload like we have for the [edit button](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable).When we select a file through upload button, we get that data and can send it to our backend api.